# Как автоматически сохранять скриншоты страницы сайта каждый час?

Tags: php, windows, веб-программирование, графика, скриншоты

Как автоматически сохранять скриншоты страницы сайта каждый час?

P.S. Желательно с помощью php скрипта, запускаемого со своего сайта и сохраняющего скрины там же, например, в какую-нибудь папку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариантов много:

Например, на Delphi - `TWebBrowser` на форму, на неё же `TTimer` и через заданные промежутки времени сохранять содержимое в `TJpegImage`. Правда, `TWebBrowser` не имеет канвы, поэтому придётся чуток пошаманить, но ничего сложного не предвижу. :)

Ну, а если совсем лень, идём и качаем бесплатно [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/download.html) - движок запуска JS из консоли. В примерах есть скрипт rasterize.js, который и делает скриншоты. Простейший запуск:

```
phantomjs.exe rasterize.js  http://site.com test.png
```

Сохранит нам скриншот в файл test.png. Копируем строку с запуском в BAT/CMD и добавляем в Планировщик Windows, с запуском каждый час.
Если нужно, - подшаманиваем строку, добавляя параметры (там можно задавать размер, форматы и т.п.)

На PHP: а почему бы не воспользоваться тем же PhantomJS? Например, так (это для Windows, для Linux будет, разумеется, слегка по-другому):

```
$ret = exec('Диск:/Путь/phantomjs.exe rasterize.js http://site.com test.png');
```

Но если нужен нативный PHP, то под Windows выбирайте между функциями [imagegrabwindow](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagegrabwindow.php) и [imagegrabscreen](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagegrabscreen.php). Только в первой функции, как я понимаю, будет зависимость от размера окна. Со второй вообще всё просто:

```
<?php
$image = imagegrabscreen();
imagepng($image, 'myscreenshot.png');
?>
```

А с первой - немного возни:

```
<?php
$window = new COM('InternetExplorer.Application');
$handle = $window->HWND;
$window->Visible = true;
$window->Fullscreen = true;
$window->Navigate('http://site.com');

while($window->Busy){ com_message_pump(4000); }

$image = imagegrabwindow($handle, 0);
$window->Quit();
imagepng($image, 'myscreenshot.png');
?>
```

Питон: сын подсказывает про библиотеку python-webkit2png. Но тут я не силён.

Comment: Для информации: проект PhantomJS остановлен в пользу развивающегося "безголового режима" у Chrome.

Comment: Viktor Tomilov, огромное спасибо... Кстати, я подумал о php... (добавил p.s. в вопрос)... А не добавите в ответ идеи, решения сделать что-нибудь на базе php тупо запускаемого с некого сайта. Я с php могу работать... ) Delphi под руками нет... )

Comment: @D-side Жаль, я с ним познакомился достаточно недавно, и пользовался весьма частенько

Comment: @user Обновил для PHP

Comment: *сын подсказывает...* - хорошая смена растет =)